# GSE1015N A spatial reference system named "NAD83_SRS_1" does not exist

Tags: db2, spatial, db2-luw

I am following this tutorial

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm-1202db2spatialdata1/index.html

And, running the sql "Listing 3. Contents of import_counties.sql" in IBM DB2 (on Windows), the CLP returns this error:
[image]

Is there anyone experienced this error before, could you please tell me how I get it solved? Because I already googled, and tried out many solutions including reinstall DB2 but the problem is still there. Is there any place that I can download "NAD83_SRS_1" and install it separately.

Comment: Did you actually enable Spatial Extender during the installation? It's not installed by default.

Comment: Yep, I have it enabled from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that there was a bug when I enable the databases to support spatial function.

```
db2se enable_db sample
```

While running this command line, it was interupted, but DB2 still reports that it successfully enabled the spatial function. Actually, this command takes very long to finish (more than 5 mins in my case), which makes me thought it gets stuck and interupt it with Ctrl+C. So the solution is just to wait until it finish without touching any keyboard.